# Dot gitconfig file not reflecting when switch user on ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: git, bashrc, zsh, .profile, user-profile

Today I have installed Ubuntu22.04LTS. In that, i had a user bob and his git config is like

```
user.name=Bob B
user.email=bob@example.com
alias.unadd=reset HEAD
```

I Had another user named quealy . when i switched to the user quealy. using sudo -s -u quealy the bob gitconfig setting not reflecting.

Previously, I encountered a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, I was able to resolve it by creating and adding the following configuration.

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/keep-home with Defaults    env_keep += "HOME"
```

I followed the same but not working in Ubuntu22.04LTS

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't care what your system user name (as displayed by `echo $USER`) is, it only cares about what you configured in `~/.gitconfig` or in your project's `.git/config` files.

So if you wish to work with several different user names (or more precisely Git committer names) for different Git projects, you need to set up different users with different home directories for each of them.

Alternatively, which I find much easier and better maintainable, simply edit the `.git/config` file for each of the projects where you want a different name; add a section

```
[user]
        name = Joe Hacker
        email = joe.hacker@mymail.org
```

Notice that a value in the project's `.git/config` file overrides that same value in `~/.gitconfig`.